# Hide Kendo pie chart legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is that anyway to use jquery hide specify legend, i do try to use as following but didn't show as expected.

```
var piechart= $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
//piechart.options.series[0].visible = false;
piechart.options.series[0].visibleInLegend = false;      
piechart.redraw();
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please create a jsfiddle example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `piechart.options.series[0].labels.visible = false;` [ref here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pie-charts/pie-labels)

Comment: hi nivas, thank for your respond. The code given just disable the label, what i'm looking for is to disable/hide specify legend/series.

Comment: you mean an option for each legend to show and hide

Comment: now i understand, if you have series you want to customize each series to hide/show its legends, is that what you want

Comment: yup, actually i wanna to write a logic to hide those series with the value of 0 so that the pie chart will not that messy compare to right now.

Comment: i red the documentation i found `visibleInLegend = false;` option will do the work, can you provide a jsfiddle with your problem so that me or someone will solve the problem